# Displaying a rounded matrix

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, vector

I want to display a vector with a predefined precision. For instance, let us consider the following vector,

```
v = [1.2346    2.0012    0.1230    0.0001    1.0000]
```

If I call,

```
mat2str(v, 1);
```

the output should be,

```
1.2    2.0    0.1    0.0    1.0
```

If I call,

```
mat2str(v, 2)
```

the output should be,

```
1.24    2.00    0.12    0.00    1.00
```

and so on.

I tried this code, but it resulted in an empty matrix:

```
function s = mat2str(mat, precision)
    s = sprintf('%.%df ', precision, round(mat, precision));
end


mat2str(similarity, 3)

ans =

    Empty string: 1-by-0
```

How can I display a vector with a predefined number of decimal places?

Comment: Can you explain why round(mat,precision) is not what you want? How is mat2str different from round

Comment: There is already a [`mat2str`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) function in matlab. It is usually a bad idea to define functions that have the same name is the built in function

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got now? What results are you getting? What have you done to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [format specifier for `sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) already provides an easy way to do this by using `*` for the precision field and passing that value as an argument to `sprintf`. Your function (which I renamed to `mat2prec`) can therefore be written as follows:

```
function s = mat2prec(mat, precision)
  s = sprintf('%.*f', precision, mat);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function roundedmat2str(X,N)
    NN = num2str(N); % Make a number of the precision
    for ii = size(X,1):-1:1
        out(ii,:) = sprintf(['%.' NN 'f \t'],X(ii,:)); % create string
    end
    disp(out)
end


X=magic(3)+rand(3);N=2;
MyRounding(X,N)
8.69    1.03    6.77    
3.32    5.44    7.80    
4.95    9.38    2.19

X = X(:).'; 
MyRounding(X,N)
8.69    3.32    4.95    1.03    5.44    9.38    6.77    7.80    2.19
```

Note that `sprintf` and `fprintf` already do implicit rounding when setting the number of decimals.

Also: please don't use existing function names for your own functions or variables. Never call a sum `sum`, a mean `mean`, or a mat2str `mat2str`. Do things like `total`, `average` and `roundedmat2str`. This makes your code portable and also makes sure you don't error out when you're using your own function but expect the default and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

This one works on my Matlab 2014b:

```
function s = mat2str(mat, precision)
    printstring=strcat('%',num2str(precision),'.',num2str(precision),'f','\t');
    s = sprintf(printstring, round(mat, precision));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted to do in the first place:

```
s = sprintf(sprintf('%%.%df ', precision), mat)
```

**EDIT**

In case you want to extend your question to matrices, you could use this slightly more complicated one-liner:

```
s = sprintf([repmat(sprintf('%%.%df ', precision), 1, size(mat, 2)) '\n'], mat')
```

One noticeable difference with the previous one-liner is that it ends with a carriage return.

Comment: IMO this is the best way to do this.

Comment: @kedarps except that it doesn't work for matrices, it creates a row vector of every input matrix.

Comment: Actually, the OP is dealing with vectors. Reference to matrix is actually due to your own edits of the OP's question.

Comment: Well, any vector is a 1D matrix. But sure, your answer answers the question, it's just not extendable to matrices. Your edit is, of course. As a side-note, if you want people you're responding to to read your comments, please use the `@username` syntax.